# PHP - Search String for a Specific Word Array and Match with an Optional + or -

Tags: php, arrays, cpu-word, match

I need to search a string for a specific word and have the match be a variable.  I have a specific list of words in an array:

```
$names = array ("Blue", "Gold", "White", "Purple", "Green", "Teal", "Purple", "Red");

$drag = "Glowing looks to be +Blue.";

$match = "+Blue";

echo $match

+Blue
```

What I need to do is search `$drag` with the `$names` and find matches with an option `+` or `-` character and have `$match` become the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a regular expression by joining the terms of the array with `|`, and adding an optional `[-+]` at the beginning:

```
$names = array ("Blue", "Gold", "White", "Purple", "Green", "Teal", "Purple", "Red");

$drag = "Glowing looks to be +Blue.";

$pattern = '/[-+]?(' . join($names, '|') . ')/';

$matches = array();

preg_match($pattern, $drag, $matches);

$matches = $matches[0];

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
string(5) "+Blue"
```

If you want to insure that you match only `+Blue` and not `+Bluebell`, you can add word boundary matches, `\b`, to the beginning/end of the regex.

If you want to find all instances of all words, use `preg_match_all` instead.

Comment: Is there a way for the result to be just +Blue by itself instead of +Blue and Blue?

Comment: Err, yes, take `$matches[0]`. Matches contains the full match, and then any sub-groups, and my regex happens to use one sub-group around the search words. See update.

Comment: "Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string" I guess this must be due to the old PHP version GoDaddy has installed.

Comment: No, it's because you're not giving it a string. Your second parameter, `$drag` in my example, has to be a string. I'd wager that's completely consistent with every version of PHP since `preg_match` was introduced.

Comment: Not sure what it was but it is working fine now after re-pasting the code.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you paste the code, or actually read the code and understand it? I left out `$drag` and `$names`, so if you just blindly pasted the code over top of what you had, of course it wouldn't work. JakeGould has since edited those variables in, so it would work if you copy-pasted the entire block, but really, you should take the time to read and understand the code you're putting in your program.

Comment: Yes I read it and am trying to learn PHP.  Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can if you use `prey_match` and some regex logic.

```
// Set the names array.
$names_array = array ("Blue", "Gold", "White", "Purple", "Green", "Teal", "Purple", "Red");

// Set the $drag variable.
$drag = "Glowing looks to be +Blue.";

// Implode the names array.
$names = implode('|', $names_array);

// Set the regex.
$regex = '/[-+]?(' .  $names . ')/';

// Run the regex with preg_match.
preg_match($regex, $drag, $matches);

// Dump the matches.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => +Blue
    [1] => Blue
)
```