# Check if an array element is in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, strpos, stripos

This question has been asked before about strings, however *none of the questions I've reviewed (not mods do not remove or tell us this is a duplicate please) actually answer my question.

I have a landing page with a simple signup via email box. Recently people have been abusing it by entering foreign characters such as *, #, $, % and also using profanity on purpose (you can always tell). I have an array of banned characters and words I'm using as follows

```
$banned = array("f**k", "f******", "blah", "*", "#", "$", "%");
```

I can tell for sure someone has been purposely trying again and again to get through it because I've missed out some characters and suddenly a bunch of addresses have been entered making no sense at all. I need to know how to use a For loop to go through and find if the following contains any of the banned words in the array

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

I have tried using

```
$arrlen = count($banned);
for($i=0; $i < $arrlen; $i++) {
    if(stripos($email, $banned[$i] !== false) {
        echo 'Banned word or character!';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Email signed up!';
    }
}
```

This did not work at all! I tried an old function is_str_contain but the error of function does not exist came back.

I tried the normal strpos as well, still no joy.

Comment: What does: *This did not work at all* mean ? Did you got: `PHP warning: Did not work at all at line 4` ? Also add error reporting (`ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`) to the top of your file(s) and check for errors + Give us a real example

Comment: Sidenote: if this is intended to go in a db and/or as a subscription, you should ideally use a confirmation method. If the email doesn't get confirmed, don't let it in. That's how you keep the riff-raff out ;-)

Comment: Just to add this in the comments, you are missing a bracket `)` in your if statement

Comment: Sorry I know I only just noticed that, my bad, but that's just in typing it out here, having the missing bracket in place made no difference. Also Rizier123, by not working I mean it still displayed the message 'Email signed up!' so that pretty much says it didn't work, I used several bad words and banned characters. Still allowed it through.

Comment: A quick 10 second search on this very site returns several threads already giving correct answers to exactly this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467036/match-array-words-against-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795789/check-if-string-contains-word-in-array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930558/php-search-string-for-a-specific-word-array-and-match-with-an-optional-or I would suggest you practice your search-foo to find your answer.

Comment: @GeordieDave1980 I'm not kicking for points here, but I posted a working method almost a 1/2 hour prior to this comment; unsure if you saw it or not. Plus, mine, is NOT an edit "after the fact".

Answer (score 1):

I've been tinkering at the idea since I didn't have a ready-made piece of code to help out.

The following works:

```
$banned = array("badword1", "badword2", "blah", "*", "#", "$", "%");
$_POST['email'] = "emailbadword1@example.com";
$email = $_POST['email'];

    foreach ($banned as $ban) {
        if (stripos($email, $ban) !== FALSE) {
            echo "Match found."; 
            return true;
        }
    }
    echo "No match found.";
    return false;
```

Plus, as I mentioned in comments; you should be using a confirmation method sent via email if you're not already doing so. If that person does not confirm their email address, then ***"stop the presses".***

Comment: No response from the OP, so I am moving on. *arrivederci*

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$banned = array("****", "*******", "blah", "*", "#", "$", "%");

$email = $_POST['email'];
foreach ($email as $em) {
    //if (strstr($em, $banned)) { // mine version
    if (strpos($em, $banned) !== FALSE) { // Yoshi version
        echo "Match found"; 
        return true;
    }
}
echo "Not found!";
return false;
```

Comment: Why should OP *try like this* ? What did you changed and why?

Comment: None of these seemed to work. I tried each one and still the entered email address was allowed through.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate through each banned word and look if your email contains any of the banned word/character.

```
$banned = array("****", "*******", "blah", "*", "#", "$", "%");
$email = $_POST['email'];
$banned = false;
for($i=0; $i < count($banned); $i++) {
    if(strrpos($email, $banned[$i]) != FALSE ) {
       $banned = true;
       break;
    }
}
echo $banned ? 'Banned word or character!' : 'Email signed up!'
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stripos` as

```
foreach ($banned as $v) {
    if (stripos($email,$v) > -1){
        echo 'Banned word or character!';
    }else{
        echo 'Email signed up!';
    }
}
```

Comment: This only worked for the first word in the array, everything else after that when entered allowed it through and display 'Email signed up!'. I can't seem to find anything that works at all.

Comment: Then remove that `break` from the loop. I've added break in order to check that if any of these word match then no need to check for the further values

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Still only caught on the first word in the array. Seriously do not understand why nothing is working.

Comment: It should be `if (stripos($email,$v) !== false){...}` because if the banned word is on the beginning stripos returns 0 (as the position) which would be interpreted as false.

Comment: If you are going to copy @Fred-ii- then at least copy all of it correctly or better still dont copy

Comment: I didn't copied any `@Fred-ii-` answer @RiggsFolly. The reason I've changed my answer is because it'll throw `warning` while checking for value `*` within `preg_match` that's why else I've no reason to replace my answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly Did you downvoted my answer. If it seems to be copied code then I'll delete my post

Comment: @Ushia the comment was written when your code wasn't edited. Stop blaming ppl for things they wrote before you edited your answer.

Comment: @TobiasJ I'm not blaming anyone over here if it looks harsh then I'll take my words back and sorry for that behavior

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions ?

```
if( !preg_match( '/(\b' . implode( '\b|\b', $banned ) . '\b)/i',
 $_POST['email'] )) {
     echo "Match found"; 
}
```

Comment: Question? Or Answer? Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Implode an array and search for the given string in an imploded array string. The code does that.

Comment: Edit your post to add an explanation.